# How to extract all links from page using iMacros & save them to file

Tags: url, hyperlink, extract, imacros

**I want to extract all urls from a single page using iMacros, then save it to CSV. I got nothing so far :)**

Comment: This is not a question

Answer (score 2):

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:* EXTRACT=HREF
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=urls.csv
```

Play the above macro in loop mode with the ‘Max:’ value > than the number of links on your page. (E.g. set it to 99999 and manually stop the macro when tags aren’t found any more).